# Can "ne" be used to refer to 1.) animate objects and 2.) an argument of a noun?

Tags: word-usage, grammar, pronouns

In a german.stackexchange thread, in a discussion about the role of animacy in German grammar, someone had listed examples from Romance languages for comparison, in which it was claimed that "ne" can not refer to people.

> Ne ho sentito parlare = I have heard of it. (strictly inanimate)
>
> Ho sentito parlare di lui = I have heard of him.

Is this actually correct, is it colloquial? There seem to be usages on the web such as:

> E’ da molto tempo che non vedo Enrico e Gianni, non ne so niente.
>
> Da quando è partita sua sorella, Maria ne parla sempre con nostalgia perché ne sente molto la mancanza.
> (https://www.pul.it/cattedra/upload_files/16350/28%20particella%20ne.pdf)

Also: Can it refer to the argument of a noun i.e. is the following possible?

> Non ho visto una foto di lui -> Non ne ho visto una foto.
>
> I have not seen a photograph of (it/her/him).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original meaning of *ne* (from Latin *inde*) is “from there”, as in

> entrò in casa e ne uscì dopo qualche minuto.

But in modern Italian it's a normal 3rd- and 6th-person pronoun, to be used in all cases where you would say *di/da lui/lei*, and often more idiomatic than that:

> si accostò alla sorella e ne sfiorò la mano.

(Source of the examples: Serianni, *Italiano*, VII.52/53.)

For further examples from great authors:

> si trovò in un letto dell'infermeria, nelle mani del frate chirurgo (i cappuccini *ne* avevano ordinariamente uno in ogni convento) [Alessandro Manzoni, *I promessi sposi*, Ch. 4]
>
> Eppure Oliva sapeva bene come il Malagna fosse diventato ricco! Me *ne* diceva tanto male, un giorno, poi, per questa ricchezza appunto, lo sposò. [Luigi Pirandello, *Il fu Mattia Pascal*, Ch. 4]
>
> mentre il papa doveva funger da mediatore tra i più potenti cardinali di Roma, ve *ne* furono alcuni come un Colonna e un Orsini, che segretamente sostenevano le nuove tendenze di povertà [Umberto Eco, *Il nome della rosa*, “Primo giorno - Sesta ”].

And I have just taken three famous novels and looked for suitable uses of “ne”...

As for the second question, you might well say *Ne ho visto una foto*, but *Ho visto una sua foto* is here slightly more idiomatic. In other situations, however, the sentence with *ne* is the more idiomatic one (as in the above example about the sister's hand: *e sfiorò la sua mano* would sound a bit less natural).